# 3D model bad quality in Onirix Targets player app

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, target

I have created a scene with a 3D model from sketchfab. The model looks great inside the Studio, but when I take a look at the same scene with the player app, the colors other details like reflections look different.

sketchfab model

[image: image sketchfab model]

Onirix Targets player app

[image: image Onirix Targets player app]

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

PS: This is the model I am using: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/back-to-the-future-tribute-for-sketchfab-a95e48f00a8245c997d365f0b46158ea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if the designer applies a post-processing filter to their model. More details at:

https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000728943-Post-Processing-Filters

In order to maintain the same effect with Onirix, you need to implement your own application with the Onirix Mobile SDK for Unity:

https://developer.onirix.com/onirix-sdk/targets-sdk

Within the Unity editor, you can modify the visual effects and filters. This way you can make the model look the same. Please also see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-Effects.html